# A nodes rejoin contradiction in Raft

Tags: raft

A contradiction in Raft make me confuse, which is:

There are 3 nodes in a raft cluster: n1, n2, n3.

1. n1, n2, n3 are running, n1 becomes leader and accepts value v1 from client.
2. n1, n2, n3 commit v1.
3. n1 disconnects and try to upon election, its term increases.
4. n2, n3 keep running, n2 becomes leader and accepts value v2, v3; n2, n3 commit v2, v3.
5. n1 reconnects and n2 disconnects.

And here is the problem, n1 doesn't get the committed value(v2, v3) so it can't become leader; term of n3 is smaller than n1 so it can't become leader; The raft cluster can't work.

Is there something wrong in the description above?

Answer (score 0):

To understand where the steps get wrong, it worth to state few rules in Raft.

1. Not every term will have a leader. If a node initiates an election, the voting may be split or the majority of nodes might not be reachable. In any case, if an election failed, then the node will take a random delay, then increate the term and retry the election for the new term (unless another leader was elected).
2. A leader stays being a leader till it hears about a higher term. As it was stated in the item 1, the higher term might have no leader - that's ok. But as soon as a leaders sees a message (vote or a heartbeat) with higher term, then the leader turns itself to a follower.
3. As usual, a follower listens for heartbeats from the leader. When a follower hears nothing for a bit (preset interval + randomized delay), then the follower turns into a candidate. The candidate will increase it term and start an election.
4. As soon as any node hears about larger term, it turns itself into a follower and uses that new term as a base. The new term may come from another leader or from a candidate

4.1 Common issue with followers being disconnected in case of vanilla implementation of raft: a disconnected follower will think that the leader is dead and it will become a candidate at some point. It will increase its term and start an election. Of course, the election will fail, as the node is disconnected; so the node will keep increasing the term. Assuming the rest of the network is stable, as soon as this node will rejoin, one of two things may happen: a) it will initiate a new election or b) it will receive a heart beat from the leader with smaller term - which will force the leader to move to follower according to rule #2 from above. In anyway, a new election will happen.

With these statements in hands we can see your steps:

1. While N1 is disconnected, it will keep considering itself as a leader. There is no term increase here.
2. When N1 reconnects (and N2 disconnects) two things may happen:

a) N1 will send heart beat to N3. N3 will reply with higher term, which will force N1 to became a follower.

b) N3 will send a heart beat to N1. N1 will learn that there is a higher term available, and N1 will turn itself to a follower.

In either case, the final configuration is N3 being the leader and N1 being the follower. And, as usual, values from N3 will flow to N1.

Comment: The confusing point for me is that: the disconnected node has a larger term, so the other node cannot win the election(in my example when it gets connected, one of the normal node gets disconnected); And it also has not data, so it cannot win the election either. Therefore the system is in a dead lock, none of them can win the election.

Comment: I think I can provide a better description to the answer; let me do that

Comment: @huangyt39 to your specific question: n1 won't be a leader with higher term as it won't initiate an election. Even if it would, it would never win it as it can't get the majority due to being disconnected. As a general though, it is not a problem that there is a node with higher term - as long as there is zero or one leader per term - that will guarantee that there is no deadlock